# conditionally disable material-table's column with Switch style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have a material-table with 4-5 columns.

I allow user to ADD, EDIT and DELETE rows using on onRowAdd, onRowUpdate and onRowDelete functions. Everything seems to be working fine without any issues. The only thing which is missing is a bit of a odd behaviour of the 'status' column which is basically an on and off switch with Materil-ui  element. When user deletes a row, the status column (which is of type Swtich) is still enabled and user can change the status which is a bit misleading from UI point of view. i.e. whehn user has deleted a row, I want this Swtich to be disabled. I tried several different options including adding a function and returning 'disabled' text from the function and use it in the column declaration as per below but nothing works...any ideas?

the isDelete() function just returns 'disabled' based on the **rawStatus** value. The rawStatus value gets set in the **onRowDelete()** promise.. see towards the end of this post

```
const isDeleted = (data) => {
    return data.rawStatus === "delete" ? "disabled" : "";
  }
```

My 'status' column definition is as per below ...

```
{
      field: "status",
      title: "Status",
      editable: "never",
      headerStyle: {
        width: 50,
        minWidth: 50,
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      },
      render: (data, id) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          control={
            <Switch
              disabled={isDeleted(data)}
              checked={data.status}
              onChange={(e) => changeStatus(data, e)}
              name="status"
              color="primary"
            />
          }
          label={data.status ? "Active" : "Disabled"}
        />
      ),
    }
```

my **onRowDelete** function is as per below where I set the **rowStatus** element value (to be used in API to perform required CRUD operations)

```
onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
                  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      const dataDelete = [...usersData];
                      const index = oldData.tableData.id;
                      if (oldData.recordStatus !== "existing") {
                        dataDelete.splice(index, 1);

                        setUsersData([...dataDelete]);
                      } else {
                        oldData.recordStatus = "delete";
                        oldData.disabled = true;
                        dataDelete[index] = oldData;
                        setUsersData([...dataDelete]);
                      }

                      resolve();
                    }, 1000);
                  }),
```

Comment: Can you create a sandbox and share link

Comment: here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-darkness-7t28m

Comment: @techipank any updates?

Comment: Updated my answer with working sandbox link have a link lemme know if it's not working...if it is working accept the answer and close this ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isDeleted` function is returning String but to disable Switch we should be returning true or false modify `isDeleted` as follows

`const isDeleted = (data) => { return data.rawStatus === "delete" ? true : false; }`

As I can see in your codesandbox now you are returning true or false from `isDeleted` which is correct but next issue was your condition in `isDeleted` Function it was written as

`return data.rawStatus==="delete"? true:false`

but in your schema there is no value for `rawStatus` that is the reason it was always returning false and your switch button was not disabled.

Condition should be

`return data.recordStatus === "delete" ? true : false;`

Corrected codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-rhodes-pzr12)

Comment: thanks @techipank, already tried that .. it doesn't work. I guess the <Switch /> API expects a word 'disabled' to disable the switch hence I was returning a text 'disabled'

Comment: perfect @techpank .. thanks for spotting my mistake. it works now.